# What's the significance of "Splashware"?

Tags: archaeology

I've found at Wikimedia Commons a few dishes labeled as "Splashware". Imitation Splashware in fact. It seems to be related to archaeology, so I hope this is the right place to ask the question (instead of English SE).

What is splashware, who used it, and when?

[image: Example 1] - [image: Example 2]

Comment: I added a second line to give your question historical significance. See my meta post:https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/is-it-ok-to-ask-general-questions-about-fashion-and-furniture-items-found-by-arc/3559#3559

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Splashware](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/449713) is earthenware "splashed" with polychrome glazes. It falls under the heading of Islamic art, and was found in places like Nishapur, Iran around the turn of the first and second millennia.

[Here](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/481603753875798101/) are some other examples of this Iranian art form.

It was perhaps inspired by porcelain from Tang China.

Comment: Thanks. And what is the meaning of "imitation" in that context? Modern pottery trying to simulate ancient Splashware?

Comment: @Fructibus: I believe that some of the pieces required heavy "restoration,"  perhaps using modern methods. That would make them no longer "originals." I don't like the word "imitation," because I don't think that's really the case. The term that I would use is "based on," as in "based on a true story." That is,they are partly "original" and partly "restored."